# How to configure Cisco SG550XG switch to use a LAG as stacking port (add up bandwidth of multiple physical ports between stack members)

Tags: cisco

We have two Cisco SG550XG and we would like to stack them over an LAG (link aggregation group, aka trunk) of 4 physical ports on each side.

According to the product data sheet this is possible and supported:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/550x-series-stackable-managed-switches/datasheet-c78-735874.html

> High-speed stack interconnects
>
> Cost-effective high-speed 10G fiber and copper interfaces. Support LAG as stacking interconnects for even higher bandwidth.

Unfortunately I am not able to configure it properly.

When I setup the stack vie the web frontend, I can only select physical ports. I did this, but it seems as if there is only 1x 10G used.

The CLI command show stack links gives:

```
Topology is Chain

Unit Id Active Links Neighbor Links Operational Down/Standby
Link Speed Links
------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------
1 te1/0/19-22 te2/0/19-22 10G
2 te2/0/19-22 te1/0/19-22 10G

CLI command show stack configuration gives:

Unit Id After Reboot Configuration

Unit Id Stack Links
-------- ------- ---------------
1 Auto te19-22
2 Auto te19-22
```

Also when creating the stack via CLI config stack configuration links te 19-22

it does not give different results.

I've also created LAGs on both switches before stacking, but that does not make a difference.

I can not use the LAG as stack port via CLI "stack configuration links lag 2"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to chat support: the answer is too easy:

when you create a stack and add multiple connections / links / cables, the stack will automatically use them in parallel (if they are active).

You can check the link status via cli:

show stack links detail